# trying to group individual students by their ID# in order to analyze student gender distribution , each student has multiple rows for each class taken

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I got the aggregate function to work and group individual students by their ID# but it won't display their gender, just says N/A, im new at programming so if you can explain where I'm going wrong that would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to analyze student performance and want to see how many males vs females there are as a first step.

[image: the error code I am getting]

here is a sample of the code I am trying:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rm(list=ls())
fake.data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                    Gender = c("M","M","M","M","F","F",'F',"F","F","F", "M", "M", "M"),
                    RolledGrade = c("A", "A-", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A-", "A-"),
                    InstructorCode = c("IO", "ED", "IA", "SA", "BA", "BA", "SA", "IA", "EA", "IO", "ED", "ED", "ED"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



grouped_by_gender<- aggregate(fake.data$Gender, fake.data["ID"], FUN = "mean")
```

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example. I think you have the right steps in there, but you might have an error in extracting xlsx columns into your data frame.

Comment: @jackkelly how would I go about fixing that! is there anything I should change in the FUN = part?

Comment: I can't help you without an example dataset to see what is going where. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @jackkelly ohhhh okay one sec

Comment: @jackkelly I made an example dataset! let me know!

Comment: please specify the desired output. Do you want to count M vs F?

Comment: Yes! Male vs female with only one count per student

Answer (score 0):

I am still having trouble understanding what you want as an output.

Maybe this is what you are looking for or a start to get you where you want.

```
library(dplyr)
grouped_by_gender <- fake.data %>%  
group_by(ID, Gender) %>% 
tally()
```

Comment: This code works in that it grouped the students by their ID and gave me their Gender, thank you!